# How to display two type of collections as two table views for singel entity in active admin with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I would like to display the two different views for single resource in single page as different collection of records. as well as sort and search filters should be work for both views in single page.

How to do this in active admin interface? Is there any way? or need to override whole index action and do display two tables in custom partial.